# How to set password to zip file with libZip

Tags: c++, libzip

I'm using [libZip](https://libzip.org/) in my project,
I success to create zip file output, but I'm having difficulty to set a password to a zip file.

I'm calling the [zip_set_default_password](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_set_default_password.html) fucntion and I'm getting the OK response, but when I'm trying to extract it didn't ask for a password.

Code sample:

```
int CompressWithPassword(const char * psFileContent, int iFileSize, const char * pcPassword)
{
    zip_source *psZipSource = NULL;
    zip_int64_t iIndex = 0;
    int iError = EOK;
    const char * pcZipOutputPath = "/home/user/Documents/myzip.zip";

    // Open zip file.
    m_psZip =
            zip_open(pcZipOutputPath,
                    ZIP_CREATE /*Create the archive if it does not exist*/,
                    &iError);

    // Zip opend ?
    if(iError != ZIP_ER_OK)
    {
        Close();
        return iError;
    }

    // Generate zip source content.
    psZipSource =
            zip_source_buffer(m_psZip,
                              psFileContent,
                              iFileSize,
                              0);

    // Valid zip source ?
    if(psZipSource == NULL)
    {
        Close();
        iError = -1;
        return iError;
    }

    iIndex =
            zip_file_add(m_psZip,
                         pcZipOutputPath,
                         psZipSource, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
    if(iIndex < 0)
    {    
        Close();
        return iIndex;
    }

    // Create password
    int iRetPassword =
                zip_set_default_password(m_psZip, pcPassword);

    // password set ?
    if (iRetPassword == -1)
    {
        Close();
        return iRetPassword;
    }

    // Close zip file.
    Close();

    return iError;
}
```

When I'm calling this function, I'm getting OK and the zip file is created, What I'm missing here?

LibZip version 1.1.3-1, OS: fedora 25

Thanks.

Comment: Not related to what you are asking, but; you do know that the password on a zip file is trivially breakable - right? Don't rely on that for any real security.

Comment: From the function name and documentation it seems that `zip_set_default_password` only sets the default password for when encryption is used it says nothing about activating encryption. You probably also need to call https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_file_set_encryption.html

Comment: @Eelke, thanks for your clarification, I now see that `zip_file_set_encryption` is from libzip version 1.2, and I'm using the older version 1.1.3, so I'll have to update first, and then I'll test it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I saw that has a lot of people searching by this question, then i'll make an example of zip_file_set_encryption, the method basically ask for zip archive, file index,encryption method and the password:

```
int main(){
    int errCode = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open("package.zip",ZIP_CREATE,&errCode);

    zip_source_t *source;

    char buffer[] = "Hello world!";
    source = zip_source_buffer(z,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    zip_file_add(z,"example.txt",source,0);

    /* Available encryption methods: 
    ZIP_EM_AES_128
    ZIP_EM_AES_192
    ZIP_EM_AES_256
    */

    zip_file_set_encryption(z,/* Index of the file */ 0,/* Encryption method */ ZIP_EM_AES_256,/* Password to encrypt file */ "myPassword");

    zip_close(z);
};
```

then when i use 7-zip to open the zip file created by my program:

```
7z e package.zip
```

It just prompt the password to me, if you type the correct then the files  in your workspace will be filled with the content:

```
Enter password (will not be echoed):
```

with the libzip is possible set file password by name, but with a little process before:

```
int main(){
    int errCode = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open("package.zip",ZIP_CREATE,&errCode);

    zip_source_t *source;

    char buffer[] = "Hello world!";
    source = zip_source_buffer(z,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    zip_file_add(z,"example.txt",source,0);

    source = zip_source_buffer(z,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    zip_file_add(z,"example2.txt",source,0);

    // Create struct of file stat
    struct zip_stat st;

    // Fill the struct with the file name that you want
    zip_stat(z,"example2.txt",0,&st);

    // Set the password to the file using index that had got by name

    /* Available encryption methods: 
    ZIP_EM_AES_128
    ZIP_EM_AES_192
    ZIP_EM_AES_256
    */

    zip_file_set_encryption(z,/* Index of file */ st.index, /* encryption method */ ZIP_EM_AES_256, /* password */"myPassword");

    zip_close(z);
};
```

I'm creating an wrapper for libzip (not complete yet), an easy way to interact with zip files, the GitHub URL is there: https://github.com/Romulo-Moraes/zipCrafter

**Caution, if you set an password to a file, you should set the same password for the whole zip file, cause it can generate an error when you try open with 7-zip, it will try open the first file with your password then will try the same password for the whole zip.**

**Some unzip program versions will skip your file that was set with password by libzip, i recommend 7-zip**

Comment: `zip_file_add` returns the index of just added file, so you do not need to call `zip_stat` for that

Comment: Yes, thanks for comment, i just wanted show a way for do it by file name, sometimes is more human readable than just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the Libzip Documentation [here](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_set_default_password.html), 'zip_set_default_password' will "sets the default password used when accessing encrypted files", if you use 'zip_fopen' to open files. otherwise, if you have a different password for single files you can use 'zip_fopen_encrypted' to open them.

If you want to encrypt files you add to an archive you need to use 'zip_file_set_encryption' with (m_psZip, iIndex, method you choose, pcPassword).

Comment: Some example how to use `zip_file_set_encryption` would be great, because it is not easy to find such in the web.